# What is the difference creating event callback or the activity itself within a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Lets say I will be using several fragments(`Action1Fragment`, `Action2Fragment` etc.) within an activity(`ActionActivity`). I want to access some elements of activity object, or call some methods of `ActionActivity`. It is generally offered to [create a event callback](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#EventCallbacks) . What if I keep a reference to `ActionActivity` within `Action1Fragment` instead of keeping a reference to `CallBackInterface` which is actually implemented by `ActionActivity` since I will be using these fragments only within a particular activity.

I am kinda confused by the idea that Activity might be dead while reference of interface might still be alive(it sounds ridiculous when I read it again but it is OK if I managed to explain myself).

Comment: When you use callbacks. You can easy use your Fragments without other Activities too. It's better that you're Fragment doesn't know anything from the Activity which it will be used in.

Comment: @Francescoverheye for the case that multiple activities use same fragment I understand, but the explained situation is kinda a fragment belongs to a particular activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android Developer tutorials recommend that you use a callback interface on your fragments. The activity that hosts the fragment must implement the callback interface. The fragment does `getActivity()` and casts it to the callback interface, and then makes the callback.

This is the recommended way to promote a more modular design. It would not matter if your fragments will only ever work inside one activity. But if you want to make more generic fragments that could be used by different activities, then the above design pattern starts to become useful. (For example: a telephones fragment inside an person fragment and a company fragment.)

Suppose you do it the other way: the fragment does `getActivity()` and casts it to `PersonActivity`. The fragment then has access to all the public methods of PersonActivity. But this design pattern becomes much more ugly when you need the other activity to also use the fragment. The fragment would then have to be changed to first try and cast to PersonActivity, and if that throws, try the `CompanyActivity`.

The recommended design pattern basically gives you a way to make an activity compatible with the fragment instead of vice versa. The fragment only knows about the callback interface and not about any of the activities itself. The activities do know about the fragment because they implement the callback interface but they already knew about it because they constructed and initialized an instance of it.

Does that make sense?

Comment: So it is just a design pattern and nothing with background business such as finished, long dead activity references... Hmm..

Comment: Yes, it has nothing to do with background threads. It has everything to do with making your code modular.